# How to domain redirect with URL content?

Tags: .htaccess, blogs, redirect

I recently moved my blog to separate domain, so I'm trying to define the URL redirect to my blog in my former site.

What I want to do is http://sub.exmple.com/blog/{any page} should redirect to http://www.new-blogdomain.com/{old page url}

The code I'm trying is:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.exmple.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new-blogdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The above code works if I go to sub.exmple.com/{any page} and goes to http://www.new-blogdomain.com/{old page} but this RULE should apply if my old URL contain blog keyword http://sub.exmple.com/blog/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below rule,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://www.new-blogdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: thank for your response. now nothing works. it goes to www.sub.example.com

Comment: still same output. Only this time it doesn't redirect to www.sub.example.com

Comment: How come it is redirecting to `www.sub.example.com` do you have some other rules too.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.exmple\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^\/?blog\/(.*)$ http://www.new-blogdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

instead of `^\/?blog\/(.*)$`,  you can try either `^blog\/(.*)$` or `^\/blog\/(.*)$`, depending on server configuration